# Unable To Find Registry Path on Local Disk

Tags: windows, registry

I would Like to access the registry path given below I tried to run with Cmd but got System cannot find path Specified error.
Please help me locate this path I have also checked inside Regedit but no luck.

**PATH**

HKU\S-1-5-21-476251715-2947723853-16432991-1000\Software

Answer (score 1):

That is a registry path so you cannot access it with `cmd`!

The path component that starts with `S-` is a SID, it identifies an account on your machine. `-1000` means it is probably the first account you created.

These keys under the HKU root are only loaded when that particular user is logged in. You can load the key manually by loading that users `ntuser.dat` file from their profile directory in Regedit but it is easier to just log in as that user.